# Java Spark : Task not serializable error while deleting directories from HDFS

Tags: java, apache-spark

In my spark job when I am trying to delete multiple HDFS directories, I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
> serializable  at
> org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>
> **

org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)

> at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:750)
> at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
> at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
> **by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem Serialization stack:
>
> - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem, value:**
>   DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_123456_1,
>   ugi=tester@TEST.KRB.CLUSTER (auth:KERBEROS)]])
> - element of array (index: 2)
> - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
> - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
> - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class com.test.Cleaner,
>   functionalInterfaceMethod=org/apache/spark/api/java/function/VoidFunction.call:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V,
>   implementation=invokeSpecial

I am using the org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem to delete the folders.

Below is my code snippet:

```
hadoopConfiguration = sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration();
hdfsFileSystem = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration);
        
hiveDayPartitionsRdd.foreach(day -> {
            String hdfsSourcePartitionPath = String.format("%s/day=%s/src=%s", "/test/path", day, "testcode");
            log.info(String.format("Deleting the src partition: %s", hdfsSourcePartitionPath));
            hdfsFileSystem.delete(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfsSourcePartitionPath), true);

        });
```

I tried the following to make it work:

1. making the **hdfsFileSystem** transient
2. **Using foreachPartition**
   instead of Foreach and declaring "hdfsFileSystem =
   FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration);" inside the for each partition

The above approaches did not solve the issue

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Please do not hesitate to propose if you know a better approach

Comment: In your solution 2, you are supposed not just to assign to `hdfsFileSystem`. You are supposed to declare it as a local variable. Did you do that?

Comment: do you really need to to that on the executors? Otherwise just collect the rdd on do the operation on the driver

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Yes, I tried declaring a local variable inside the foreachPartition, but i am still getting the serialization error

Comment: @ Raphael Roth: I prefer to parallelize the deletes as the RDDs can contain huge number of paths to delete.

Comment: @smang did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @chathux , I did not succeed in resolving the serialisation issue. However, as the number of partitions that I have will not be huge, I went ahead with rdd.collect().foreach() to proceed with the delete operation on the driver side